# How can I import png images into a JSZip?

Tags: javascript, jszip

I am trying to put an image in my jszip but it give me an error every time

This is my jszip code:

```
function button(res){

    setTimeout(function(){ 


        var zip = new JSZip();
        var img = zip.folder("image");



        var base64 = require('./base64');
        var ZipEntries = require('./zipEntries');
        module.exports = function(data, options) {
        var files, zipEntries, i, input;
        options = options || {};
        if (options.base64) {
        data = base64.decode(data);
        }
        }

        zip.folder("images").file("facebook.png", base64Data, {base64: true});



        base64zip = zip.generate();



        zip.file('signature.html', res );
        zip.generateAsync({type:"blob"})
        .then(function(content) {
            saveAs(content, "mailssignature.zip");

        });
    }, 2700);

};
```

Comment: Please click "edit" under your post and include any console.log error messages that are occurring.

Comment: Which version of JSZip do you use ? You used `generate()` (JSZip v2) and `generateAsync()` (JSZip v3) in the same function.